# Unable to select a row in gridview in Asp.net c# WebForms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in an Asp.net c# web application that I populate using a sqldatasource in the code behind.  The gridview ma

```html
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgAssnmtList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" ShowGroupPanel="True" Skin="Default" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rgAssnmtList_SelectedIndexChanged" OnPreRender="rgAssnmtList_PreRender" OnItemCommand="rgAssnmtList_ItemCommand">
                <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="True" AllowColumnsReorder="True" ReorderColumnsOnClient="True"></ClientSettings>
                <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="assnmtIdPk">
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="LinkButton" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="assnmtIdPk" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="assnmtIdPk" SortExpression="assnmtIdPk" UniqueName="assnmtIdPk" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter assnmtIdPk column"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" UniqueName="Id" FilterControlAltText="Filter Id column"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="clientIdPk" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="clientIdPk" SortExpression="clientIdPk" UniqueName="clientIdPk" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter clientIdPk column"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="clientNm" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Client" SortExpression="clientNm" UniqueName="clientNm" FilterControlAltText="clientNm" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="assnmtClmNo" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Claim" SortExpression="assnmtClmNo" UniqueName="assnmtClmNo" FilterControlAltText="assnmtClmNo" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="invNo" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Invoice" SortExpression="invNo" UniqueName="invNo" FilterControlAltText="invNo" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="assnmtCrtdDt" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Rcd. Date" SortExpression="assnmtCrtdDt" UniqueName="assnmtCrtdDt" FilterControlAltText="assnmtCrtdDt" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="inspDt" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Inspection Date/Time" SortExpression="inspDt" UniqueName="inspDt" FilterControlAltText="inspDt" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="stat" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="stat" UniqueName="stat" FilterControlAltText="stat" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FirstName" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName" UniqueName="FirstName" FilterControlAltText="FirstName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LastName" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName" UniqueName="LastName" FilterControlAltText="LastName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

The sqldatasource is:

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Identify the current user
            crntUserId.Value = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
            //crntUserIdLbl.Text = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

            //populate a hidden control with the current user's ID
            hdnCrntUsr.Value = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
            string currentUserId = hdnCrntUsr.Value;

            //populate a hidden control with the current user's company Id and another with the company name
            SqlDataSource sdsAssnmtList = new SqlDataSource();
            sdsAssnmtList.ID = "sdsAssnmtList";
            this.Page.Controls.Add(sdsAssnmtList);
            sdsAssnmtList.DataSourceMode = SqlDataSourceMode.DataSet;
            sdsAssnmtList.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            sdsAssnmtList.SelectCommand = "SELECT anu.Id, anu.FirstName, anu.LastName, uc.clientIdFk, c.clientNm FROM AspNetUsers anu INNER JOIN AspNetUserComps uc ON anu.Id = uc.anuIdFk INNER JOIN clients c ON c.clientIdPk = uc.clientIdFk WHERE Id = @Id";
            sdsAssnmtList.SelectParameters.Clear();
            sdsAssnmtList.SelectParameters.Add("Id", currentUserId);

            System.Data.DataView assnmtListDV = (DataView)sdsAssnmtList.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            DataTable assnmtListDT = assnmtListDV.ToTable();
            DataSet assnmtListDS = new DataSet();
            assnmtListDS.Tables.Add(assnmtListDT);

            DataRow row = assnmtListDT.Rows[0];
            hdnCompId.Value = row["clientIdFk"].ToString();
            hdnCompNm.Value = row["clientNm"].ToString();


            //populate the grid based on the role and company of the current user
            //can see all of the assignments in the system
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("AKOB") || (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("aQA") || (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("aMgr"))))
            {
                SqlDataSource sdsAkobAssnmtList = new SqlDataSource();
                sdsAkobAssnmtList.ID = "sdsAkobAssnmtList";
                this.Page.Controls.Add(sdsAkobAssnmtList);
                sdsAkobAssnmtList.DataSourceMode = SqlDataSourceMode.DataSet;
                sdsAkobAssnmtList.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
                sdsAkobAssnmtList.SelectCommand = "SELECT a.assnmtIdPk, c.clientIdPk, c.clientNm, a.assnmtClmNo, a.assnmtCrtdDt, invs.invNo, " +
                                                   "i.inspDt, s.stat, anu.FirstName, anu.LastName " +
                                                   "FROM assnmts a " +
                                                   "INNER JOIN clients c " +
                                                   "    ON a.assnmtClientId = c.clientIdPk " +
                                                   "LEFT JOIN insps i " +
                                                   "    ON a.assnmtIdPk = i.assntIdFk " +
                                                   "LEFT JOIN invoices invs " +
                                                   "    ON a.assnmtIdPk = invs.assnmtIdFk " +
                                                   "INNER JOIN assnmtStats aStats " +
                                                   "    ON a.assnmtIdPk = aStats.assnmtIdFk " +
                                                   "INNER JOIN statuses s " +
                                                   "    ON aStats.assnmtStat = s.statIdPk " +
                                                   "INNER JOIN( " +
                                                   "            SELECT a2.assnmtIdPk, MAX(aStats2.assnmtStatDtSet) AS MaxDate " +
                                                   "            FROM assnmts a2 " +
                                                   "            INNER JOIN assnmtStats aStats2 " +
                                                   "                ON a2.assnmtIdPk = aStats2.assnmtIdFk " +
                                                   "            GROUP BY a2.assnmtIdPk " +
                                                   "           ) mdt " +
                                                   "    ON a.assnmtIdPk = mdt.assnmtIdPk AND aStats.assnmtStatDtSet = mdt.MaxDate " +
                                                   "INNER JOIN repAssnmts ra " +
                                                   "    ON a.assnmtIdPk = ra.assnmtIdFk " +
                                                   "LEFT JOIN AspNetUsers anu " +
                                                   "    ON anu.Id = ra.repAssnmtRep " +
                                                   "INNER JOIN( " +
                                                   "            SELECT a3.assnmtIdPk, Max(ra2.repAssnmtCrtdDt) AS MaxDate2 " +
                                                   "            FROM assnmts a3 " +
                                                   "INNER JOIN repAssnmts ra2 " +
                                                   "    ON a3.assnmtIdPk = ra2.assnmtIdFk " +
                                                   "GROUP BY a3.assnmtIdPk " +
                                                   ") mdt2 " +
                                                   "    ON a.assnmtIdPk = mdt2.assnmtIdPk AND ra.repAssnmtCrtdDt = mdt2.MaxDate2";
                sdsAkobAssnmtList.SelectParameters.Clear();

                rgAssnmtList.DataSource = sdsAkobAssnmtList;
                rgAssnmtList.DataBind();

                assnmtMgrTabStrip.Visible = true;

                rgAssnmtList.MasterTableView.GetColumn("assnmtIdPk").Display = false;
                rgAssnmtList.MasterTableView.GetColumn("Id").Display = false;
                rgAssnmtList.MasterTableView.GetColumn("clientIdPk").Display = false;
            }}
```

The gridview is populated just fine.  I get the correct records.  When I click on the "Select" LinkButton the row is selected and another gridview is populated with it's data based on the primary key (assnmtIdPk) in rgAssnmtList.  This works as well.

The new gridview is:

```html
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgJournals" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsRgJourns" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" ShowGroupPanel="True" Skin="Default">
                        <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="True" AllowColumnsReorder="True" ReorderColumnsOnClient="True"></ClientSettings>
                        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="journalIdPk" DataSourceID="sdsRgJourns">
                            <Columns>
                                <telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="LinkButton" CommandName="Select" Text="Select"></telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="journalIdPk" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="journalIdPk" SortExpression="journalIdPk" UniqueName="journalIdPk" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter journalIdPk column"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="assnmtIdFk" HeaderText="assnmtIdFk" SortExpression="assnmtIdFk" UniqueName="assnmtIdFk" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter assnmtIdFk column"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="journEntCrtdBy" HeaderText="journEntCrtdBy" SortExpression="journEntCrtdBy" UniqueName="journEntCrtdBy" FilterControlAltText="Filter journEntCrtdBy column"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="journEntCrtdDt" HeaderText="journEntCrtdDt" SortExpression="journEntCrtdDt" UniqueName="journEntCrtdDt" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter journEntCrtdDt column"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="journTitle" HeaderText="journTitle" SortExpression="journTitle" UniqueName="journTitle" FilterControlAltText="Filter journTitle column"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="journEntry" HeaderText="journEntry" SortExpression="journEntry" UniqueName="journEntry" FilterControlAltText="Filter journEntry column"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </MasterTableView>
                    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

And it's sqldatasource is:

```html
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsRgJourns" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>' 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [journalIdPk], [assnmtIdFk], [journEntCrtdBy], [journEntCrtdDt], [journTitle], [journEntry] FROM [journals] WHERE ([assnmtIdFk] = @assnmtIdFk) ORDER BY [journEntCrtdDt] DESC">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="rgAssnmtList" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="assnmtIdFk" Type="Int32"></asp:ControlParameter>
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

At this point I expect to be able to click the "Select" button in the new gridview (rgJournals).  But I am unable to select a row, and I don't get an error.

Am I missing something in the sqldatasource for rgAssnmtList?  Maybe some select parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is specific to the Telerik RadGrid.  When I switched to using just the asp:GridView it worked as expected.  I just won't be able to use their product for this specific project.  This comment is being left just-in-case anybody else runs into this same issue in the future with this product.